# IIS Gzip compression refuses to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, gzip

I've looked at every question on this site regarding this issue but none of the solutions worked for me! I know I must be missing something small, but I just can't find it.

I'm using windows 7 and IIS 7.5. So I've added the following to the system `applicationHost.config`:

```
 <section name="httpCompression" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

I've installed Static and dynamic compression and enabled them for the site. 
And added the following to my `web.config`

```
     <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" >
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" doStaticCompression="true"  />
        <dynamicTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

But still it does not work. I tried FailedReqLog module to debug this issue but no log files are created. I can't even see `httpCompression` in my configuration editor in IIS. 
[image]

I've been trying different solutions for the past 3 days. I'm totally out of ideas. Debugging options are most appreciated if there is a way to trace this issue and see why could it possibly not be following the web.config setting. Even worse why is it not showing it in the configuration editor.

Answer (score 0):

By default on IIS 7.5, if the file size is less than 2,700 KB then compression will not be used. Another exclusion is by CPU utilization. By default, if CPU utilization is over 90%, compression will not be used.

Since this is on your development box, maybe your file sizes are too small. You can change the defaults.

Reference [IIS HTTP Compression](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression).

Comment: They are actually compressed in the directory specified in `httpCompression`. But the compressed version is not served! I even tried setting the min filesize to 1 but still no change. I'm really confused as I'm not sure what sequence IIS follows and can't debug it

Comment: If you're doing all testing locally on your box, I wonder if the browser or IIS are automatically determining that there is no performance benefit.  Have you tried that config with the browser on a different machine from IIS?  Or locally, try browsing using your machine name instead of localhost.